Dividing a polygon into squares on Google Earth Engine
I have a polygon and  I would like to divide them into squares and analyze the NDVI time series in each of the square on GEE.
I already have the code for the NDVI analysis and I'm looking for a way to divide my polygon into several squares on GEE browser.
How can I do this?
This is the code for the polygon I would like to divide.
 var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[140.41796279738332, 38.55462820706246],
          [140.47014785597707, 38.528849190890654],
          [140.90685439894582, 38.30504425048466],
          [141.06066299269582, 38.274863735666166],
          [141.21172500441457, 38.40196801696368],
          [141.19799209425832, 38.53529481115387],
          [141.16231772536065, 38.58469329788129],
          [141.08812881300832, 38.616889342084235],
          [140.40972305128957, 38.6083048089192]]]); 



"Squares" in decimal degrees aren't really squares, they're spheroidal trapezoids, and each row would have a different area.

To create a grid over a polygon you can use .coveringGrid. You may force a projection and scale and perform your analysis based on such a grid, considering how this may affect your end goal. As @Vince pointed in the comment "Squares aren't really squares and would have different areas". I added area to each feature in the grid as property to illustrate this point. Finally, you also need to decide how to handle the edge cells intersecting the roi boundary as non-complete edge "squares".
   var Gridded = roi.coveringGrid('EPSG:32654',1000)
Map.addLayer(roi, {}, 'roi')
Map.addLayer(Gridded, {}, 'Gridded')
var Intersection = Gridded.map(function(f){ f= f.intersection({'right': roi, 'maxError': 1})
return f.set({'area':f.area(0.1), 'id':f.id()})});
Map.addLayer(Intersection,null,'edgPoly_Intersection')


Thank you so much. I have question regarding the ID of the divided polygon. I tried applying the EVI time series code for each of the divided polygon and exported the csv with the following code.
Export.table.toDrive({
collection: ee.FeatureCollection(eviTimeSeriesCollection),
description: 'EVI_Polygon_' + (index + 1),  // IDをエクスポート名に追加
fileFormat: 'CSV',
selectors: ['decimalYear', 'meanEvi']
I got EVI_Polygon.csv from number  1 ~ n ( n: number of divided polygon) but I have no idea which csv is for which polygon. How do I deal with this problem?

You can id as a property to each feature as we did for the area. I added 'id':f.id() inside a map function in the code above to address this

Is it possible to use the polygon ID for the csv file I want to export?
For example if the ID of the divided polygon is (97,851), I want the csv file name EVI_Polygon_97,851.csv
This is the code I'm using for the export.
Export.table.toDrive({
collection: ee.FeatureCollection(eviTimeSeriesCollection),
description: 'EVI_Polygon_' + (index + 1),
fileFormat: 'CSV',
selectors: ['decimalYear', 'meanEvi']
});

Using id as a name means you will have a csv file for each feature, and you have N features > 100,000 !! Unless I misunderstood the task, what you will probably find more useful is one csv file that contains information for all feature : i.e., a csv file with N*years row and columns' names: 'id','Year', 'meanEvi', 'area' etc... which is what the code do. (alternatively, you can make a csv file per year too) Either way, it would depends on how you calculated 'eviTimeSeriesCollection')

In this case, I'm trying to divide the region into several parts ( around 60~100) and then analyze the EVI time series in each region. I think I kind of solved the problem by adding  polygon ID after the index in the exported csv.
Thanks for helping.
